# ¿Cómo navego de una pagina ContentPage a una Shell en Xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, app

Tengo una app en Xamarin sencilla, tengo un Login que es un ContentPage, necesito que después de loguearse vaya a una ShellPage, con NavigationPage no me funciona ya que deberia hacer la pagina Shell una pagina Navigation Page.

Aquí esta mi Codigo de Login

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Ingreso_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

        }
    }
```

Mi ShellPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : Shell
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

y mi App:

```
public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Login());
        }
```